# How to include target/generated-sources/jaxb folder in jacoco coverage report?

Tags: maven, junit, sonarqube, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

While running the application, I am getting the total coverage including the `target/generated-sources/jaxb` folder. In local i.e. eclipse IDE this folder is included but not in jacoco report. PSB the screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6odG.png)

But while checking the jacoco report, in that this `target/generated-sources/jaxb` folder is not included. How to include this folder in jacoco report?

[Another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQSBh.png)

because of this my sonar is also not showing the combined coverage of the FOSSIL_CLIENT folder.

How can I include this folder in the coverage part?